# FreeBSD Mysql 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, freebsd

MySQL is running, verified by service mysql-server status.

Here is my config file (/etc/my.cnf):

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
language = /usr/share/mysql/English
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

3306 is open (sockstat -4 -l):

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
root     sendmail   749   4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:25          *:*
root     sshd       746   4  tcp4   *:22                  *:*
mysql    mysqld     714   10 tcp46  *:3306                *:*
root     syslogd    424   7  udp4   *:514                 *:*
```

mysql.user Host for User root is set to wildcard %

Any ideas what else I could do?

Comment: There are two users from root, one for the host and one for the unix socket. So make sure you have one for the host (aka port based) based user also present.

Comment: Try to use `IP`, if you want to login with a user uses '%', and MySQL will not refresh the memory data if you use `UPDATE` statement to modify the mysql.user, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is needed.

Comment: how are you connecting?

Comment: @WangWen'an thanks I will try it out as soon as I am home and keep you posted.

Comment: @danblack I am using navicat to connect.

Comment: @JigarPatel Do you mean two users in the mysql.user table?

Comment: Is navicat connecting to the same socket that is in the mysqld config?

Comment: @JigarPatel I granted all privileges and flushed them. This is how it looks now https://i.imgur.com/z2C9v6W.png however it is still the same error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wang the issue is solved. How do I mark this question as solved?